# Illustrator Adjusting the shape of a brushed path using paintbrush yields unpredictable behaviors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a question regarding adjusting the shape of an existing brushed path using paintbrush tool.

I created a brushed path using Paintbrush tool. After selecting the created path, I used paintbrush tool to adjust its shape.
Here is when the unpredictable behaviors come in.

Sometimes it adjusts the existing path from where you start dragging. Sometimes it extends the path instead.

What controls the behavior?

The video should clarify my problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHCV2fsNUFc

Comment: Double click on the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the tool. If the end is within the edit distance it extends the path otherwise it edits it. You can disable the functionality if you wish.